# Is a partial answer OK?

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to give a partial answer as an answer?

I had a problem with adding icons to a manifest.
But I formulated the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852600/where-do-i-edit-manifest-webapp/)(see original edit) wider to cover all aspects of manifest manipulation.

When I finally found out how to add icon I wrote that down as an answer so others might find it.

My question here is not about me answering my own question, I could just as well have given that answer to someone else.

So far that question has got one delete vote and two comments that don't think the information is relevant to the original question.

What should I have done?

Should I have avoided formulating the question to broadly and asked a new question for every property when I needed it?

Or are these reactions normal to SO and nothing to worry about? (I did indeed get a good broad answer, although in the form "you can't yet")

Comment: From personal experience, providing a partial answer will get you downvotes. Thus the community response is that partial answers are bad answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO you should post a new question regarding icons in particular and answer it. You could then add a link in your original question explaining that the new question contains a partial answer.

If, as you suggest in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852600/where-do-i-edit-manifest-webapp/#comment38914452_24852695), it will happen that, in time you would accumulate knowledge to answer the question fully, then you can post an answer there.

Comment: I was about to write a second question/answer pair but realized that the difference would have been extremely small, so I modified the original question since it did not interfere with answers given by others.

I like your suggestions here for another time, thanks.