# "Don't know what they don't know"

Tags: discussion

These are questions where the OP is asking about a piece of logic which is embedded in code that is very poorly written or is very new to a topic.  Many times these questions are unclear - and arguably should be closed, but sometimes they offer an opportunity to clarify issues which may be helpful for others.

This could be described as "don't know what they don't know."

Is it better to try to help the OP and other readers, even if your answer ends up being slightly different than the question asked?

This is assuming that the question cannot be improved with comments.

For example the OP is confused about two different terms and asks a question that makes no sense because they don't understand either of them. Would it be better to clarify the two terms or close the question?

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing) because this question is aimed at helping someone who probably lacks the skills and experience to request help properly.  This would be the case where someone posted a question and although there really is no way to answer what they asked, it is possible to help them learn and understand more about what they are working with.

Comment: Are you asking if it's OK to post a helpful answer to a question? As opposed to something else?

Comment: The intent was as @JasonC suggested - is it okay to post a helpful answer to a question - even if it isn't exactly what the OP asked.  In that case, you understand you are deliberately offering a valid answer that may not address the question, but would like to help the OP and other readers improve their skills.

Comment: "[...] but sometimes they offer an opportunity to clarify issues which may be helpful for others" -- Are those issues related to what is being explicitly asked? If they are unrelated and require a digression long enough that it obscures the answer proper, it is sensible to close as "too broad".

Comment: These are related issues.  For example the OP is confused about two different terms and asks a question that makes no sense because they don't understand either of them.  Would it be better to clarify the two terms or close the question?

Comment: According to these comments, this question isn't a duplicate of the one it was closed against. You might want to edit it to incorporate the comments and make the difference clearer, which hopefully would help in getting it reopened.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers I received and will use what I learned.

Comment: This may be a worthwhile duplicate-like post: [Is a partial answer OK?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267126/is-a-partial-answer-ok)

Comment: RE your edit: that's *exactly* why you should vote to close the question and then use comments to clarify exactly what they are trying to ask. Stack Overflow is not designed to give general programming advice to people who don't know what they don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If somebody posts a question, and you spot a more fundamental issue, and you believe you have an answer that can help them, yes, absolutely, post the answer. Answers are intended to help the poster with their problem, and if you believe yours does, don't think twice about it.

If the question is unclear, and you are guessing, sure, post away if you want. Worst that can happen is it doesn't answer their question. Best that can happen is it does. They said, in this case, you may wish to ask for clarification first, or perhaps vote to close. Clarifying unclear questions is itself a form of helping the OP and other readers.

Now if the question is so far gone that you're taking a complete stab in the dark, it's probably better for everybody if you ask for clarification, answer or not. But if you see some clarity where others do not, go for it.

Don't forget about comments, too. If all you want to do is e.g. clarify some misused terms, that is probably more appropriate for a comment than an answer (well, unless of course said misuse of terms *is* the actual problem). Your answer does need to *attempt* to answer the question, of course. If your attempt is a guess that's totally OK, but if your input isn't an attempt, consider a comment instead.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your comment:

> > "[...] but sometimes they offer an opportunity to clarify issues which may be helpful for others" -- Are those issues related to what is being explicitly asked? If they are unrelated and require a digression long enough that it obscures the answer proper, it is sensible to close as "too broad".
>
> These are related issues. For example the OP is confused about two different terms and asks a question that makes no sense because they don't understand either of them. Would it be better to clarify the two terms or close the question?

That being so, it is not so much that your answer "may not address the question", but rather that it doesn't make sense to address the question. If the root of the weirdness of the question can be pinpointed, and there are no other issues that would require closing the question, it is fine to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

> This is assuming that the question cannot be improved with comments.

I think that's not possible. Comments are made to improve questions. If a question cannot be improved and you answer it according to your understanding than other people who could not understand the proper meaning as you extracted from it will down vote it. Than you have to remove your answer or question will be closed.

> but sometimes they offer an opportunity to clarify issues which may be helpful for others.

Than this opportunity cannot be availed. I think questions should be improved as it is intended for others also. Make the question as much understandable as you could by helping the OP.