# What is the etiquette on modifying a post when progress is made?

Tags: discussion

I have a coding issue that I am addressing, and I came up with a 90% correct solution.  So I posted this question: [Dynamic dropdown on intermediate page for admin action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393285/dynamic-dropdown-on-intermediate-page-for-admin-action)

With the help of someone outside SO, I have made some great progress -- I have a dynamic dropdown which is great but a corner case is not covered correctly.  So now I have a 99% correct solution and a new question.

Resolving the new question will provide me with a 100% solution to my original coding issue and I will then be able to post a self-solution to the already-posted question.

Is it more appropriate to make a brand-new post to ask my new question, or to refine my existing post to make my question more specific to my needs but possibly not as helpful in the general sense?

Answer (score -2):

<sup>Not sure what the etiquette is, but the votes on this answer will tell you whether the community thinks this is a good idea.</sup>

**Answer your own question with your partial solution, but don't accept it (yet).**

1. Partial solutions [are valid answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144457)<sup>1</sup>.
2. Your answer can inspire other answerers, who don't know one part of the solution, but do know how to address the part you are unsure about.
3. You can accept some other answer, when it comes. Your question will not be marked as solved, so it can keep attracting interested answerers.
4. You can update your answer in case you ever figure out a 100% solution, and then accept it.

In any case, you transparently communicate the progress that you made without cluttering the site with a potentially less useful question that may even duplicate your first one.

_____
<sub><sup>1</sup> Just make sure that your partial answer does address your question, otherwise it [might be downvoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267126).</sub>

Comment: Regarding that footnote: the answer might get downvotes no matter what; partial solutions are not really quality answers after all. I'm not sure it is worth the risk to be honest.